# Grep a text from file and print the above line starting with a pattern

Tags: linux, perl, text

textfile-1

```
SAR001
SAR005
SAR008
SAR010
SAR012
.
.
.
```

textfile-2

```
C 0001 Carbon [C]
D SAR001 methane [CH3]
D SAR002 ethane
D SAR003 propane
D SAR004 butane
D SAR005 pentane
C 0002 Hydrogen [H]
D SAR006 hydronium
D SAR007 water [H20]
C 0003 Nitrogen [N]
D SAR008 ammonia [NH3]
D SAR009 ammonium chloride [NH4Cl]
D SAR010 amide
C 0004 Oxygen [O]
D SAR011 ozone
D SAR012 super oxide
.
.
.
```

Desired output

```
SAR001 Carbon [C]
SAR005 Carbon [C]
SAR008 Nitrogen [N]
SAR010 Nitrogen [N]
SAR012 Oxygen [O]
.
.
.
```

My query is grep text from textfile-1 in textfile-2, and after that print the third column of the above line starting with "C". Any shell or perl based script is welcome. I am using OpenSUSE linux.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
perl -anE '
  BEGIN{ open($f,pop)||die$! }
  if ($F[2]) { $c = $F[2]; next }
  $s{ $F[1] } = $c;
  END{
    s|\s+$||, s|$| $s{$_}|, say while <$f>;
  }
' textfile-2 textfile-1
```

output

```
SAR001 Carbon
SAR005 Carbon
SAR008 Nitrogen
SAR010 Nitrogen
SAR012 Oxygen
```

---

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{ open($f,pop)||die$! }
  @F = split /\s+/, $_, 3;
  if (!/SAR/) { $c = $F[2]; next }
  $s{ $F[1] } = $c;
  END{
    s|\s+$||, s|$| $s{$_}|, print while <$f>;
  }
' textfile-2 textfile-1
```

output

```
SAR001 Carbon [C]
SAR005 Carbon [C]
SAR008 Nitrogen [N]
SAR010 Nitrogen [N]
SAR012 Oxygen [O]
```

Comment: `I don't like to see answers to this question` would be fair comment from down voters.

Comment: ok @fedorqui, RobEarl, toolic, amon and Borodin. I will first try it. And will edit my question with the attempted script.

Comment: Dear mpapec, this script is only retrieving the textfile-1 as it is. Kindly help.

Comment: This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi.

Comment: @MuhammadSufian perhaps your txt files differ from these posted above

Comment: Still not working. I have edited my question's textfile-2. There is a third column in rows starting with D, and also some text in square brackets. Kindly ignore my mistake as I am a newbie. I will not do this again.